# Parameters specified in function automatically passed to filter

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I wrote a function and filters to analyze a CSV file's contents.

Function to create a pipeline of column objects:

```
function Analyze {

        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param(
          [String]
          $File
        )

        # get column headers from CSV; enumerate
        $Headers = (Get-Content $File | Select-Object -First 1).Split(',')
        $Headers | ForEach-Object {

          # create an object that represents each column; initialize values
          $Column = [PsCustomObject]@{'Name'=$_;'Measurements'=@()}

          # add to pipeline
          $Column
        }

}
```

Filter to calculate the minimum value of each column's contents:

```
filter Min {

    Param(
        [string]$File
    )

    # create Logparser query
    $Query = "SELECT Min($($_.Name)) AS Minimum FROM '$File'"

    # excute query; return results as XML
    [xml] $xml = & logparser $Query -stats:off -o:xml

    # create object to contain measurement and its value
    $Measurement=[PsCustomObject]@{'Name'='Minimum';Value=$xml.root.row.Minimum.Trim()}

    # add to collection and return to pipeline
    $_.Measurements+=$Measurement
    $_

}
```

Filter to calculate the minimum value of each column's contents:

```
filter Max {

    Param(
        [string]$File
    )

    # create Logparser query
    $Query = "SELECT Max($($_.Name)) AS Maximum FROM '$File'"

    # excute query; return results as XML
    [xml] $xml = & logparser $Query -stats:off -o:xml

    # create object to contain measurement and its value
    $Measurement=[PsCustomObject]@{'Name'='Maximum';Value=$xml.root.row.Maximum.Trim()}

    # add to collection and return to pipeline
    $_.Measurements+=$Measurement
    $_

}
```

Usage:

```
pushd C:\users\<user>\Desktop
$File = '.\d.csv'
Analyze -File $File | Min -File $File | Max -File $File
popd
```

Is there a way to architect the filters such that I can call it like:

```
pushd C:\users\<user>\Desktop
Analyze -File '.\d.csv' | Min | Max
popd
```

Comment: You can add file property to objects by `Analyze` function.

Comment: @PetSerAl, I considered that, but it seemed like a hack.  Maybe it's the only way...

Comment: You have to have it returned to the pipe somehow if you expect the next function to use it.

Comment: @craig Have you considered adding `-Min` and `-Max` parameters to `Analyze` rather than having separate filters?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, so `-Min` and `-Max` are `Switch`es?  If true, call the desired filter within the `ForEach-Object` loop?  If so, would it make more sense to refactor the filters as functions?

Comment: Yes, or just use the presence of `-Min` and/or `-Max` to construct the desired `$Query`, rest of the filters are identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Mathias R. Jessen's comments, I refactored the function and filters:

```
function Analyze {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
        [alias('f')]
        [String]
        $File,

        [Switch] $Min,
        [Switch] $Max,
        [Switch] $Top
    )

    # get column headers from CSV; enumerate
    $Included = (Get-Content $File | Select-Object -First 1).Split(',')

    $Included | ForEach-Object {

        # create a hash that represents each column; initialize values
        $Column = [PsCustomObject]@{'Name'=$_;'Measurements'=@()}

        # apply specified filter; pass object via pipeline
        if ($Min) { $Column | Min -File $File }
        if ($Max) { $Column | Max -File $File }
        if ($Top) { $Column | Top -File $File }

        # add to pipeline
        $Column

    }

}
```

Needed to disable the filter's pipeline:

```
filter Min {

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [alias('f')]
    Param(
        [string]$File
    )

    $Query = "SELECT Min([$($_.Name)]) AS Minimum FROM '$File'"

    [xml] $xml = & logparser $Query -stats:off -o:xml
    $Measurement=[PsCustomObject]@{'Name'='Minimum';Value=$xml.root.row.Minimum.Trim()}

    $_.Measurements+=$Measurement

    # pipeline disabled; created multiple instances of Column object
    #$_

}

# similar changes to these filters
filter Max {}
filter Top {}
```

Usage:

```
pushd C:\users\<user>\Desktop
$File = '.\data.csv'
Analyze $File -Min -Max -Top
popd
```